# .htaccess root issue with php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have transfer my files to dedicated server. I have a restful api for my mobile app. It will route the folder name with parameter. The parameter will be a argument of the function and inputs. I have written the `.htaccess` file as below. but it's not working. How do i solve this?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php?rquest=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]   
</IfModule>
```

My result will be :
http://www.domain.com/rest/events it will list the values as json output its not working

But http://www.domain.com/rest/api.php?rquest=events its working. I want above method. how do i solve this

Comment: Try adding first segment /rest/: `RewriteRule ^rest/(.*)$ api.php?rquest=$1 [QSA,NC,L]` You need second segment

Comment: it's going to 404 page error found

Comment: Oo you redirect test folder. Try one: `RewriteRule ^rest/(.*)$ test/api.php?rquest=$1 [QSA,NC,L]`

Comment: i have mistakenly wrote test..it wil be rest only

Comment: have you enabled mod_rewrite? `a2enmod rewrite && service apache2 restart` in debian/ubuntu

Comment: yeah..enabled the mod rewrite

Comment: What is AllowOverride set to in your httpd.conf for that location?

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure you place this in `DOCUMENT_ROOT/rest/.htaccess`

Replace your code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /rest/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php?rquest=$1 [QSA,L]
```